# How do I generate an importmap tag with a subset of imports in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import-maps

I am currently using the `javascript_importmap_tags` helper from the standard importmap-rails gem, which generates a tag for *everything* pinned in config/importmap.rb and does this for *every page*. I'd like to include only a subset of entries, grouped for the (very) isolated parts of my site, but it doesn't seem to have this capability. (It is simple to limit which things get imported but the map itself remains unnecessarily large, including everything that might get imported across the entire site.)

Justification: My importmap is over 300 entries, most of which are for my site-specific javascript modules. Within the site, almost all of these modules can be grouped into completely independent "apps". Limiting the number of entries would be worth a little bit of effort even if just for the fact that there would be less to look at when debugging. But also, generally speaking, I want to isolate things and make individual components smaller because most things are less likely to break if there are less parts, and it's often easier to make them simpler than it is to figure out whether it is a problem for them to be larger and more complicated.

1. How can I do this while not straying too far from the default setup? Right now I'm trying to do it by making a `javascript_importmap_tags_for` helper that mimics the built-in `javascript_importmap_tags` by making a call to `javascript_inline_importmap_tag`, but the actual list of mappings provided to that method usually comes from `Rails.application.importmap`, which is created when the server starts from config/importmap.rb. I just don't know how to make either multiple import map objects, or make one importmap object with named groups without interfering too much with the way it currently works. The docs tell you how to compose a single importmap from multiple importmap.rb files, which I've tried, but it doesn't seem to help and I don't think it was intended for this.
2. Should I even be trying to do this? (Will it potentially *cause* a problem to limit the importmap in this way and/or am I wasting effort or adding more complications trying to break it up than I'm removing by making the importmap simpler on a given page?)

Answer (score 2):

It's not really designed for this (yet) and I'd be worried that you'll miss out on some of the caching Rails wraps around this and have to update it if the internal API changes.

**Are you concerned that all requests are loading un-needed JS files?**

Only the modules that are actually `import`ed in loaded code or have `preload: true` in `importmap.rb` are actually loaded (even if they show in the importmap).  Any module you (or other JS) don't import or [`modulepreload`](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/modulepreload/) won't be downloaded and used by the browser.  So in general it's *not an issue to have an unused entry in the import map*.  It may feel imperfect or even messy but the number of bits for the import map itself is likely lower than most of the images on your site.

It might be worth opening an issue to explore the willingness to add this though.  In the meantime I'd suggest **breaking up the import maps so you can customize your preloads** for the *divisions* in your site.

First minimize your `preload: true` to truly global modules as much as possible.

Then in your layout replace `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` with what it expands to:

```
    <%= javascript_inline_importmap_tag %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_module_preload_tags %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_shim_nonce_configuration_tag %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_shim_tag %>
    <%= javascript_import_module_tag "application" %>
```

Finally in the specific portions of your app where you want to preload some **more modules** for speed add those tags manually with something like:

```
    <%= javascript_module_preload_tag(Rails.application.importmap.packages["d3-color"].path) %>
    <%= javascript_module_preload_tag(Rails.application.importmap.packages["d3-time"].path) %>
```

You may want to `content_for :head` those as well unless you have multiple layouts as well.

Comment: Size could become a problem: The importmap is 44k. This would double the html size, and on mobile start making the initial page load noticeable (e.g., 300ms). Adding more apps to the site would easily make it much bigger. I could do other things to reduce it, but your steps for isolating the preloads could be used to create one map per layout. There are 5 or 6 layouts and each need almost mutually exclusive importmaps. I just need to do: `<%= javascript_inline_importmap_tag(x) %>`, where "x" is  `Rails.application.importmap` but somehow different per layout, and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: That is bigger than I anticipated.  You may want to give Alex's answer below a read; I read through it quickly and it fits with what I know.  I was concerned adding a second one may have caching issues, but that looks like it might be at least partly handled there.  I'd also suggest posting this as a feature request on the repo's issues.  I bet other folks will want this at some point.

Comment: It is huge. The size boils down to the number of entries because: my javascript is split into many small files (one for each class), those use relative imports for each other, and the caching mechanism adds fingerprints to the filenames (thus requiring a map). Changing any one of those things would help, but a large site will inevitably have a large importmap for other reasons if it only has one for the whole site. The difficulty splitting it seems like a weak point, and when you combine it with other issues, I think the recommended use of importmaps for Rails 7 is currently premature.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it's doable:

```rb
# app/assets/config/manifest.js
//= link_tree ../../javascript_two .js

# config/importmap_two.rb
pin_all_from "app/javascript_two"
```

```rb
# config/initializers/*.rb

map = Importmap::Map.new
map.draw(Rails.root.join("config/importmap_two.rb"))
map.cache_sweeper(watches: Rails.root.join("app/javascript_two"))
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app/javascript_two")
Rails.application.class.attr_accessor(:importmap_two)
Rails.application.importmap_two = map
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller_base, run_once: true) do
  before_action { Rails.application.importmap_two.cache_sweeper.execute_if_updated }
end
```

```rb
>> puts helper.javascript_inline_importmap_tag(Rails.application.importmap_two.to_json(resolver: helper))
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "another_app": "/assets/another_app-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.js"
  }
}</script>
=> nil
```

```rb
>> puts helper.javascript_inline_importmap_tag(Rails.application.importmap.to_json(resolver: helper))
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-15b16d6dc392d96a0dcc6e30c1f41abb496a3170c9c486de35da876ab020eadf.js"
  }
}</script>
=> nil
```

---

**Update**

`Importmap::Map` class relies on `resolver` to produce digested paths. This is the only thing that can be overridden without messing with importmap internals.

```rb
# app/models/my_resolver.rb

class MyResolver
  def initialize view, dir
    @view = view
    @dir = dir
  end

  def path_to_asset source, options = {}
    if source.starts_with? @dir
      @view.path_to_asset(source, options)
    end
  end

  def to_json
    Rails.application.importmap.to_json(resolver: self, cache_key: @dir)
  end
  
  # to get the importmap <script> tag
  def importmap_tag
    @view.javascript_inline_importmap_tag(to_json)
  end
end
```

```rb
<%= MyResolver.new(self, "application").importmap_tag %>

<%= MyResolver.new(self, "controllers").importmap_tag %>
```

Obviously, you'll have to make sure that each importmap includes needed dependencies.

```html
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-976dc3f309746bbfec28c82e0166c141e39eacc1727bc2fd34915c02afa0932d.js"
  }
}</script>

<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "controllers/application": "/assets/controllers/application-90dfbccab93509f543ebff5e31bf8e28a399e25e3d0cdc31a3d0669a01a614a0.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/controllers/hello_controller-3f23212d3bfb1a2ce152d8ef84c3fc5ee29acf7b2280d300a23b502032f73420.js",
    "controllers": "/assets/controllers/index-7717f93a371849ea3d8bce9f257455f80cd13dca1fc045487f376e6f8678b1b4.js"
  }
}</script>
```

Comment: I'm afraid to do this because the importmap object that is currently created automatically has things that happen to it automatically that I think would require more than the above. More importantly, updates to the gem might add to that list, and then I'd have to remember that I might need to do the same. I have another solution that I'm testing that adds methods to the Importmap::Map class so that I can filter what shows up in the importmap. I haven't posted it as an alternative answer because I haven't tested it in production yet.

Comment: @cesoid see update. maybe something like that could work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can see that
[https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/tree/main#selectively-importing-modules]
[enter link description here](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/tree/main#selectively-importing-modules)

**Selectively importing modules**

You can selectively import your javascript modules on specific pages.

Create your javascript in app/javascript:

```
// /app/javascript/checkout.js
// some checkout specific js
```

Pin your js file:

```
# config/importmap.rb
# ... other pins...
pin "checkout"
```

Import your module on the specific page. Note: you'll likely want to use a content_for block on the specifc page/partial, then yield it in your layout.

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag "checkout" %>
<% end %>
```

Important: The javascript_import_module_tag should come after your javascript_importmap_tags

```
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
<%= yield(:head) %>
```